# Видимость контрола на форме C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На форме несколько вкладок в TabControl. Есть на разных вкладках объекты CheckBox. Так вот, чтобы показать, что у меня в базе данных не просто true или false, а очень даже null, то я рядом с CheckBox делаю видимой или не видимой объект Label с текстом "Null". Но вот какая беда. Когда я создаю форму и нахожусь в первой вкладке, то в консоль по команде

```
Console.WriteLine("isVIPNullLbl.Visible  :  " + isVIPNullLbl.Visible);
```

Выводится:

```
isVIPNullLbl.Visible  :  False
```

А как только переключаюсь на нужную вкладку - true. То есть, выводится буквальное значение видим мы метку, или нет. Поэтому, когда переключаемся на другую вкладку - уже не можем использовать видимость метки как маркер того, что в таблице стоит null. Окей, попробовал использовать свойство .Enable - тут не менее интересно. Когда я создаю форму, то задаю значение False. Однако, если открыть форму и проверить (вывести в консоль) будет значение true. Однако, если переключиться разок на проверяемую вкладку и снова проверить, то будет заданное при создании значение False. При этом, в случае со свойством .Enable - можно переключаться по другим вкладкам и значение уже не изменится. Как-так то? Как мне проверить видимость метки, если она скрыта в другой вкладке?

Comment: Решение простое - храните данные в переменных, а не в контролах.

Comment: Андрей, это очень обходное решение в конкретной ситуации. Понятное дело, что можно переделать всё и сосредоточиться на отдельных переменных. Но это место останется не понятным, а это не есть хорошо. Почему .enable, например, меняется, когда первый раз переключаемся на вкладку, хотя задано при создании формы? Вот и получится, что в этой области останется магия, а хотелось бы понимать процесс.

Comment: Это не обходное решение а верное. Контролы должны беспокоиться за успешное отображение себя, а не за вашу информацию, это не их ответственность. А почему так - это вас не должно интересовать, скорее всего это какая-то оптимизация использования ресурсов внутри фреймворка. Изучите паттерны семейства MVx, в частности MVC, который применяют при проектировании WinForms приложений и делайте так как правильно.

Comment: Чтобы показать 3 состояния элемента в чекбоксе, надо юзать [CheckBox.ThreeState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.threestate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Андрей, я действительно использовал отдельную структуру для хранения null состояний (идея с тремя состояниями Checkbox мне не нравится, иначе бы использовал её - не интуитивная в данном случае). Но вопрос поставлен именно так и мне интересно, спасибо.